# android ViewPager onCreateVew() not call when change page

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

here is my code: 
 class MyDishActualBaseFragment extends Fragment

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle data = getArguments();
        categoryID = data.getInt("categoryID", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_actual_dish_layout_adapter,
                container, false);
        if (categoryID == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Page1:", 3000)
                    .show();
        } if (categoryID == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Page2:", 3000)
                    .show();

        }
        return v;
    }
```

here is class MyDishActualFragment extends FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyDishActualBaseFragment myFragment = new MyDishActualBaseFragment(
                mContext,listDishEntity);
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putInt("categoryID", pos);
        myFragment.setArguments(data);
        return myFragment;
    }
```

My problem is the Toast only display once, ("page1" and " page2" only display once when run this code) when I change page 1 -> 2, The Toast not display. So what problem is? 
 Anyone help me, thanks so much.

Comment: when you go from 1 -> 2 is every thing ok ? i mean fragment 2 is loaded correctly?

Comment: no,I run the application, first It show the 1st Page and 2 Toast( page1 and page2). Next I change to page2. And no thing display.

Answer (score 0):

This is because ViewPager doesn't recreate fragment on each swipe .. it creates fragment only once and keeps in memory and recreate once after it goes `offScreenpageLimit()` ...For recreating fragment each time  you swipe ,you have to set

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

But this method is not recommended if you have so many pages in viewpager (atleast more than 10)..

Comment: after setting adapter for viewpager in the activity @user3733430

Comment: I set myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1), but  It still doesn't work.

Comment: try myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(page_count) instead @user3733430

Comment: @user3733430 this is because this is not correct explanation of the method on your viewpager, by setting this you are saying don't recreate fragments to the left, or to the right in my viewpager. see my answer above.

Comment: am sorry it's a mistake...try myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) instead @user3733430

Comment: @sam No problem, glad to see you sam, but i think the good answer is follow inner_class7

Answer (score 0):

viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit(int) , tells the view pager you do not want to recreate the fragment at all.

see

> public void setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)
>
> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
> current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
> limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

src: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

with that said, you are providing a toast in onCreate(), if the viewPager, which by default holds on to the current fragment, one in front, and one before the current fragment you will not get the onCreate method called again, unless you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, which destroys off screen pages each time, but then you need to manage the state of the fragments, which is more useful for larger sets of fragements within an activity.

Additionally, i would just use my adapter to Toast the user, something like

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MyDishActualBaseFragment myFragment = new MyDishActualBaseFragment(
            mContext,listDishEntity);
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putInt("categoryID", pos);
    myFragment.setArguments(data);

   if (pos == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Page1:", 3000)
                .show();
    } if (pos == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Page2:", 3000)
                .show();

    }


    return myFragment;
}
```

Note: This assumes that your Adapter actually has Context.

Comment: thank you, so can I solve my problem by change extends FragmentPagerAdapter to extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I will try

Comment: Not exactly, FragmentStatePagerAdapter will require extra work with maintaining fragment state using onSaveInstaceState(Bundle b) and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle b). If all your trying to do is toast the user when the fragment changes, just look at the getItem method i posted which uses pos to check the page

Comment: Yes, all my trying to make the page 2 load new adapter when I edit the adapter on page1. 
 My page1 display listView with list<String>. When I delete one component in page1, then page2 will show this String in listview. 
 I try to do it but It seem some problem

Comment: you will have to provide more examples, i am unclear of what exactly your having a problem with. furthermore you can view my example https://github.com/lt-tibs1984/InterfaceDemo which shows fragment communication between activities and viewpager